How to logically extract a part of a WHERE clause condition and execute it outside of an SQL query later?
The scenario
Let's say we have a database table 'TABLE' with entities identified by 'ID'. Each entity has several features stored in columns (COLUMN_1 to COLUMN_N). There is an additional feature of the entities FEATURE_X that is not in the database.
An SQL query with a WHERE clause filters the entities based on conditions involving the columns and FEATURE_X.
Now we can't include FEATURE_X in the actual condition of the query that goes to the database, because that feature is not represented by a column in the database, but let's say is determined by a very slow algorithm.
The problem
I want to split the logical condition into two parts. One that involves only columns in order to send to the database and one condition involving FEATURE_X.
I want to construct a query to retrieve entities that form a superset of the actual result set, so that I can start the very slow algorithm with an already prefiltered set of potential result entities.
Is there a logical operation that ensures that we always get a superset regardless on how the logical expression is?
An example
Given an expression
Φ = (COLUMN_1 < 10)
     AND ((COLUMN_2 = 4) OR (COLUMN_3 > 5) OR NOT (COLUMN_4 = 0 AND FEATURE_X = 1))

the SQL statement would look like this:
SELECT ...   
FROM ... 
WHERE Φ

How can I exclude 'FEATURE_X' without compromising the correctness of the result?
My pseudo code that doesn't work:

Identify Φ_database
Φ = (COLUMN_1<10) AND ((COLUMN_2=4) OR (COLUMN_3>5) OR NOT (COLUMN_4=0 AND TRUE))
Identify Φ_feature_x
Φ = FEATURE_X=1
Construct SQL query
SELECT "ID" FROM "TABLE" WHERE (COLUMN_1<10) AND ((COLUMN_2=4) OR (COLUMN_3>5) OR NOT (COLUMN_4=0 AND TRUE)))
Use the result as an input for the slow algorithm and get the result.

The error here is that the first SQL query does not always return a super set but sometimes also an empty set, which means that the logical expressions in the where clause are not preserved.

I don't really understand your issue, but maybe you are after a CTE? Use it to apply the conditions you can check in the DB. And then take its result and do what you want with it, including further filtering with conditions outside the DB if you like.

Your strategy is correct, so if the first query returns an empty multiset, then that is a superset of the actual result set... that is empty. If you don't agree, please include a few rows of sample data to explain your case.

SET @table_name = 'your_table_name';

SET @column_name = 'your_column_name';


SET @sql = IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM information_schema.columns

 WHERE table_schema = DATABASE()

 AND table_name = @table_name

 AND column_name = @column_name) > 0,

 CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@table_name, 
 ' WHERE ', @column_name, ' IS NOT NULL AND id > 980'),

CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', @table_name, ' WHERE id > 980'));

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

This is what I did in my scenario.
See if this helps
